# SQL Server find time slot between start time and end time

Tags: sql, sql-server

SQL Server, how to find the time slot from a schedule table like I need to output first column's end time and next column's start time?

```
 select 
    s, e,
    Max(cid)as c_id,
    ROW_NUMBER()OVER(order by CAST(s as datetime)) as row_id
 from classroom 
 where Room like '3310' and Days like '%T%' 
 group by s,e
 order by CAST(s as datetime)
```

For example:

```
s       e       c_id    row_id
------- ------- ------- ------
9:30    10:45   235     1
11:00   12:15   236     2
12:30   13:45   238     3
14:00   15:15   1415    4
15:30   16:45   273     5
17:00   18:15   270     6
```

I need to output

```
10:45-11:00
12:15-12:30
13:45-14:00
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can insert your data in a temp table and then query that temp table

```
select s,e,Max(cid)as c_id,
    ROW_NUMBER()OVER(order by CAST(s as datetime))as row_id 
into #t
from classroom 
where Room like '3310' and Days like '%T%' 
group by s,e 
order by CAST(s as datetime)


select t1.e, t2.s
from #t t1 
    INNER JOIN #t t2 on t1.row_id + 1 = t2.row_id
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know only when there's a time gap between one class finishing and the next starting add `where t2.s > t1.e` to Abhi's answer.  If you need a minimum size of slot, say 15 minutes, use `where DATEDIFF(mi, t1.e, t2.s) > 15`.